# Custom schedule deletion in Laravel

Tags: laravel, cron

How can it be done after you set the expiration time of the record, it will be automatically deleted. After you set a specific duration older than 1 year or 6 months or 15 days it will automatically delete the record. What do I need?

[image]

Comment: do you store "retention period" and "duration" as 2 separate fields ?? i suggest to store it as single timestamp field,   for example as "deleted_on",   and use scheduled command  like "Tirta Keniten" suggested, and change query into ::where(deleted_on, <=, now())

Answer (score 2):

This is how I would do

Create a command

```bash
php artisan make:command DeleteSchedule
```

```php
<?php
// App\Console\Commands\DeleteSchedule
protected $signature = 'deleteschedule';

public function handle()
{
    Model::where('created_at', '<', now()->subMonths(18))
        ->delete();
}
```

Run a command every 1 day

```php
// App\Console\Kernel
protected function schedule(Schedule $schedule)
{
    $schedule->command('deleteschedule')
        ->daily();
}
```

Comment: how to test the command and check if that deletes?

Comment: you can run it on terminal. ``php artisan deleteschedule``

Answer (score 0):

I would not use commands, because you simply run it once a day, and dont delete records immediately.
This may cause issues, such as displaying old records of that same day, and processing them, if system is using these records to do something afterwards. Even statistics of these records would not be accurate all the time.

I would personally use jobs, and schedule them to run at the time record expires. This way record will be deleted at the same time they expire.